# How to compare two different pandas dataframe whose lengths are not equal?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, comparison

I'm having two dataframes i.e. **df1 and df2**

```
df1:                                 df2:

  Column1  Column2             ColumnA ColumnB 
0    abc       a              0  stu       aaa
1    pqr       b              1  mno       bbb
2    stu       c              2  pqr       ccc
3    mno       d              3  abc       ddd
4    xyz       e              4  xyz       eee
                              5  uiq       fff
                              6  mls       ggg
                              7  qww       hhh
                              8  dfg       iii
```

Now I want to use `column1` first value i.e. `abc` and search for this value is available in the `columnA` of the `df2`. If match found then I want that matching row's value of `columnB` in one seperate column of `df1`. (note - every entry in `column1` may available at once or none in `columnA` of the `df2`).

**Output format :**

```
df1 :
 Column1  Column2  Column3 
0    abc       a      ddd
1    pqr       b      ccc
2    stu       c      aaa 
3    mno       d      bbb 
4    xyz       e      eee
```

I tried with different scenarios. when I try to compare this dataframes like:

```
df['column1'] == df['columnA']
```

I'm getting error because length of both dataframes is not same. How I can perform this type of operation in pandas dataframe?

Comment: Sorry can't you just do `df1.merge(df2)` to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html), but first rename column `ColumnA` and last `ColumnB`:

```
print (pd.merge(df1,df2.rename(columns={'ColumnA':'Column1'}))
         .rename(columns={'ColumnB': 'Column3'}))

  Column1 Column2 Column3
0     abc       a     ddd
1     pqr       b     ccc
2     stu       c     aaa
3     mno       d     bbb
4     xyz       e     eee
```

Another solution with parameters `left_on` and `right_on`, but is necessary [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) column `ColumnA`:

```
print (pd.merge(df1,df2, left_on='Column1', right_on='ColumnA')
         .drop('ColumnA', axis=1)
         .rename(columns={'ColumnB': 'Column3'}))

  Column1 Column2 Column3
0     abc       a     ddd
1     pqr       b     ccc
2     stu       c     aaa
3     mno       d     bbb
4     xyz       e     eee
```

---

EDIT by comment:

If joined values are duplicated, rows are multipled:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['abc','a'], ['pqr','b'], ['pqr','b'], ['pqr','b']]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Column1','Column2'])


df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ColumnA': {0: 'stu', 1: 'pqr', 2: 'pqr'}, 
                    'ColumnB': {0: 'aaa', 1: 'ccc', 2: 'ccc'}})


print (df1)
  Column1 Column2
0     abc       a
1     pqr       b
2     pqr       b
3     pqr       b

print (df2)
  ColumnA ColumnB
0     stu     aaa
1     pqr     ccc
2     pqr     ccc

print (pd.merge(df1,df2.rename(columns={'ColumnA':'Column1'}))
         .rename(columns={'ColumnB': 'Column3'}))

  Column1 Column2 Column3
0     pqr       b     ccc
1     pqr       b     ccc
2     pqr       b     ccc
3     pqr       b     ccc
4     pqr       b     ccc
5     pqr       b     ccc
```

Then is possible use [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
print (df1)
  Column1 Column2
0     abc       a
1     pqr       b
2     pqr       b
3     pqr       b

df1 = df1.drop_duplicates()
print (df1)
  Column1 Column2
0     abc       a
1     pqr       b

print (df2)
  ColumnA ColumnB
0     stu     aaa
1     pqr     ccc
2     pqr     ccc

df2 = df2.drop_duplicates()
print (df2)
  ColumnA ColumnB
0     stu     aaa
1     pqr     ccc

print (pd.merge(df1,df2.rename(columns={'ColumnA':'Column1'}))
         .rename(columns={'ColumnB': 'Column3'}))

  Column1 Column2 Column3
0     pqr       b     ccc
```

EDIT1:

If `DataFrames` have more columns, is important specify join columns by parameter `on`:

```
print (pd.merge(df1,df2.rename(columns={'ColumnA':'Column1'}), on='Column1')
         .rename(columns={'ColumnB': 'Column3'}))
```

EDIT2:

If need remove rows with `NaN` in selected columns use [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
                   'B':[4,5,np.nan],
                   'C':[7,8,np.nan],
                   'D':[np.nan,3,5],
                   'E':[5,3,6],
                   'F':[7,4,3]})

print (df)
   A    B    C    D  E  F
0  1  4.0  7.0  NaN  5  7
1  2  5.0  8.0  3.0  3  4
2  3  NaN  NaN  5.0  6  3

print (df.dropna(subset=['C','B']))
   A    B    C    D  E  F
0  1  4.0  7.0  NaN  5  7
1  2  5.0  8.0  3.0  3  4
```

Comment: It's a very minor point, but it looks like you're missing a final `.rename(columns={'ColumnB': 'Column3'})` to exactly match the output.

Comment: Yes, I am doing on it. Thank you.

Comment: @jezrael- my orifinal meand df dataframe.shape returns (67387, 29). but result.shape returns (98778, 80). why dataframe df1 rows are not same?

Comment: Then there is problem with duplicates, give me a sec.

Comment: I add solution, but removing duplicates depends of your data. I think the best is test it in small sample and then apply solution to real data.

Comment: @jezrael- sorry to trouble you. In your edit, df1 column1 contains abc 1 time, pqr 3 times so, we want total 4 rows only with specific mapping between columns.

Comment: @kit - Then need remove duplicates only in `df2` - `df2 = df2.drop_duplicates()`

Comment: @jezrael- no. df2 columnA doesn't contain duplicate values. In real situation df1 contains 67387 and df2 contains 2868 rows. I think problem is because of other columns!

Comment: @jezrael- yes I already tried with that but same issue raising. In small situation it giving me correct output but in real time row gets change. Didn't understand what I'm missing

Comment: @jezrael- Got the Issue but not solution. Issue is df2 one or two columns contains more number of rows than others. now how I can remove column1 and column3 rows whose contain nan?

Comment: Please check `dropna` like `df2 = df2.dropna(['column1','column3'])`. Untested.

Comment: I add sample to answer, please check it.